# What is the maximum value of $n$ for which $3^n$ divides 1000!?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, factorial, euclidean-algorithm

What is the maximum value of $n$ for which $3^n$ divides 1000!

Am I supposed to look at it as a congruence... or apply euclid's algorithm somewhere? I'm lost

I can't use simple arithmetics... Someone help.

Comment: Just count factors of $3$.  There are about $1000/3$ multiples of $3$.  But some are also multiples of $9$, and there are about $1000/9$ of those.  And some of them are also multiples of $27$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

$3$ divides every $3^{rd}$ factor of $1000!$

$3^2$ divides every $9^{th}$ factor.

$3^3$ divides every $27^{th}$ factor.

etc.

$n = \lfloor \frac {1000}{3}\rfloor + \lfloor \frac {1000}{9}\rfloor + \lfloor \frac {1000}{27}\rfloor + \lfloor \frac {1000}{81}\rfloor\cdots\\
333+111+37+12+4+1$

Answer (score 0):

The number of $3$ in the prime factorization of $1000!$ is given by:

$$n = \left[\frac{1000}{3}\right]+\left[\frac{1000}{3^2}\right]+\left[\frac{1000}{3^3}\right]+\left[\frac{1000}{3^4}\right]+\left[\frac{1000}{3^5}\right] + \left[\frac{1000}{3^6}\right]$$
$$ = 333 + 111 + 37 + 12 + 4 + 1 = 498$$

To see why this formula is true, not that the first terms counts the number from $1$ to $1000$ divisible by $3$. The second one counts the number from $1$ to $1000$ divisible by $9$ and so on.

Comment: This makes sense...but why would you just equate that to n

Comment: @Lee Done, although it doesn't make much difference. I hope the answer was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the neither the headline nor the text does indicate some missed faculty symbol, the answer is just: 0.

1000 has no divisor 3. Nor does it have a divisor $3^n$ for any $n>0$. But $3^0=1$ surely does divide 1000.

--- rk

Comment: The exclamation point means [factorial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial). That's what makes it interesting.

Comment: Thanx for the right english word, I just translated it from German (Fakultät - applying to both meanings). - At the time of my post, that exclamation mark indeed was missing in the title line. This is why I posted the above reply!